# Stop REST WS while application is running?

Tags: java, rest, weblogic

I have an Web application publishing a webservice and deployed on cluster having two instances. LB forwards traffic to each active instance.
When I want to deploy new Application into both instances I am following the steps.

1- stop instance-A, deploy new application

2- start instance-A with new load

3- stop instance-B, deploy new application

4- start instance-B with new load

with this model there is operation loosing since when I kill the instance-A ,tasks in its queue are not processed. There is only one way to avoid from coccuring this problem,
When WS(publishing on port lets say 7002) is stopped LB understands that instance is down then does route traffic into this server

To make this way is possible internal threads keeps running while WS is stopped in other words port is killed? 
How I can make this configuration on weblogic 12c?

Comment: It is a hard problem to solve. One idea - can you redeploy your new application so it runs side by side with the old one? It can retire the old app so it finishes processing before switching to the new one: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm#DEPGD266 Then your load balancer would always work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enviroment->Server->XXXServer->Control
Select runnning instance then Suspend it. It will stop all servlet so Rest and WS services will be suspended but all internall clasess keeps running.

Thus tasks in internall queue of an Application will be completed since new one will not be send via rs and WS interface.

[image]